# I want to know how to store some data in Matlab which I can later call from Java code?

Tags: java, matlab

I want to store some data generated via Matlab and want to access it from Java code base for further processing. Please let me know how I can do it ?

Comment: zero-effort question -> zero-effort answers.

Comment: What kind of data? Only matices or complex structs?

Comment: StackOverflow has 80 questions about Java MATLAB interoperability. Browse them, you will surely find what you want.

Answer (score 1):

[JMatIO - Matlab's MAT-file I/O in Java](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10759)

> JMatIO is a JAVA library to read/write/manipulate with Matlab's binary
>   MAT-files.
>
> Currently supported data types are:
>   + Double array
>   + UInt8, Int8 array
>   + UInt64, Int64 array
>   + Char array
>   + Structure
>   + Cell array
>   + Sparase array

Answer (score 0):

[Export Data from Matlab to Text Files](http://www.myoutsourcedbrain.com/2008/11/export-data-from-matlab.html)

Answer (score 0):

[matlabcontrol](http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/)

> matlabcontrol is a Java API that allows for calling MATLAB from Java.
>   You can eval, feval, as well as get and set variables. Interaction can
>   be performed from either inside MATLAB or outside MATLAB.

Comment: hmmmm that looks interesting I may have to check that out myself.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data? If you have a plain old 2-D matrix in Matlab, it can be passed directly as a `double[][]` argument to a Java method.

See the MATLAB documentation on [passing data to a Java method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f6425.html). Note that a MATLAB `struct` cannot be passed to Java directly.

If your Java code requires method arguments that are something standard like a `List` or a `Map`, you can create an `ArrayList` or `HashMap` from within MATLAB:

```
>> m = java.util.HashMap;
>> m.put('foo',3);
>> m.put('bar',4);
>> m

m =

{foo=3.0, bar=4.0}
```